# 64bit version of python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, torch, easyocr

I am trying to install easyOCR on raspberry pi.
When i do that i get an error code, EasyOCR "version" depends on torch

So i get that i need to install torch

When i try that i get the error code; ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch
And; ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

I read that others find succes in downgrading in python version, that it should work with python 3.9
I have python 3.9.2, then i read that it should be a 64bit version. I have a 32bit version.
But i cant find a right way to install a 64bit version.

I think and hope that, that step would fix the rest.

Comment: Do you have 64-bit processor and OS on your raspberry pi to start with?

Comment: i did wonder that myself, but i dont really know how to check that.

Comment: It looks like i have an 64-bit processor, but only 32-bit OS, i will work on getting the 64bit installed. and hopefully that was the only problem.